# Linux - Cut video from end position

Tags: linux, video, ffmpeg, video-editing

I have been looking at different video cutting command line tools for Linux and I can't seem to find any which supports the operation of cutting a video from the end.

For example, i have 10 videos of variable length. I need to obtain the last 3 seconds of each video.

I looked into ffmpeg and mpgtx but to no avail.

Can someone tell me the tool/command to cut the video from end position?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried with ffmpeg? ffmpeg is suitable for this. Unfortunately a "last seconds" option does not exist, but you can use the `-ss` (time offset) and `-t` (duration) options to get the last 3 seconds.

Comment: I tried the -t option, but couldn't get it working for the last 3 seconds, hence the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following could be not the most elegant way to do that, but it works.

Insert filename to variable for convenience:

```
file="yourvideo.avi"
```

Get length of the video -3 seconds (-3 is set in `sed` command – we cut `ID_LENGTH=` and add `-3` at the end):

```
start=$(mplayer -identify -vo dummy -ao dummy -really-quiet "$file" 2>/dev/null | sed -n '/ID_LENGTH=/s/ID_LENGTH=\(.*\)/\1-3/p' | bc)
```

You can do the same thing with [avprobe](http://libav.org/avprobe.html) or [ffprobe](http://ffmpeg.org/ffprobe.html) (which come with avconv or ffmpeg):

```
start=$(avprobe -i "$file" -show_format 2> /dev/null | sed -n '/duration=/s/duration=\(.*\)/\1-3/p' | bc)
```

Cut with [FFmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) (`ffmpeg`) or [Libav](http://libav.org/) (`avconv`) with the starting position of `$start`:

```
avconv -ss $start -t 3 -i $file -vcodec copy -acodec copy end_${file}
```